# D3 always merges nodes, even with same data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, dom

I created d3 treemap component that should display two different texts, and place those inside rectangles (not in terms of html structure but positioning on the page).

As this works correctly, I noticed that when new data comes in one of text tags gets updated.
So what I think would be expected behaviour, is if data returnd from `.text` function is the same as already existing text in the DOM, do not `update` nodes, if it is different, do `update` the nodes.
What actually happens, is every time new data comes in always one of the text gets replaced.

I want to update `<text>` only when the value inside of it differs, not at all times.

Here's the code that I have:

```
import * as d3Selection from 'd3-selection';
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
// ^^^^ imports stuff

export const Heatmap = ({
  width,
  height,
  padding = 1,
  data,
}) => {
  debugger;
  const ref = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    draw();
  }, [width, height, padding, data, ref.current]);

  const draw = () => {
    const svg = d3Selection.select(ref.current);
// util to get d3-treemap, nothing out of ordinary happening here apart from adding 
// opacity, value and color attributes to each node

    const root = makeTreemap({
      width,
      height,
      padding,
      data,
    });

    const rootLeaves = root.leaves();
    svg.attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`).attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet');
    svg.attr('height', '100%').attr('width', '100%');

    const nodes = svg.selectAll('rect').data(root.leaves());

    nodes.join(
      (enter) =>
        enter
          .append('a')
          .attr('href', (d) => {
            if (d.link) {
              return d.link;
            }
            return '/';
          })
          .attr('target', '_blank')
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            return d.x0;
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y0;
          })
          .attr('width', function (d) {
            return d.x1 - d.x0;
          })
          .attr('height', function (d) {
            return d.y1 - d.y0;
          })
          .style('stroke', 'black')
          .style('fill', function (d) {
            if (d.color) {
              return d.color;
            }
            return d.value >= 0 ? 'darkgreen' : 'darkred';
          })
          .style('opacity', function (d) {
            if (d.opacity) {
              return d.opacity;
            }
            return 1;
          }),
      (update) => update,
      (exit) => exit.remove()
    );

    svg
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(root.leaves())
      .join(
        (enter) =>
          enter
            .append('text')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('x', function (d) {
              return (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2;
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
              return (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 + 15;
            })
            // just code to get string to display
            .text(function (d) {
              const titleSplit = d.title.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\s+/g);
              const [_, ...otherParts] = titleSplit;
    enter code here
              return otherParts.join(' ')
            })
            .attr('fill-opacity', 0.7)
            .attr('fill', 'white'),
        (update) => update,
        (exit) => exit.remove()
      );

    svg
      .selectAll('vals')
      .data(root.leaves())
      .join(
        (enter) =>
          enter
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', function (d) {
              return (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2;
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
              return (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2;
            })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text(function (d) {
              return d.title.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\s+/g)[0];
            })
            .attr('fill', 'white'),
        (update) => update,
        (exit) => exit.remove()
      );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width, height }}>
      <svg id={styles.svg} ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I noticed, that If I were to delete the first one of text rendering parts the nodes would get added to the DOM instead of merged upon new data arrival.

I would assume it's one of the two things

1. My understanding of when the nodes get updates is wrong, and even though the value for rendering is exactly the same in d3 `join` there is no caching of values or something similar before making DOM updates, which would mean that I would have to take care of checking if values are equal myself. (somehow)
2. I messed up at some point and d3 does update the parts because I told it to do so at all times, even when data is the samy

Either way, if it's clear for any of you my internet friends why in this particular example nodes always get updates, even if returned value from `.text(d => ...` function is the same AND how to actually avoid updates from happening I would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes always get updated because you don't specify a **key function**, which is the second argument to `data()`. Since I don't know what your data looks like, here's a simplified example: suppose your data is this:

```
data = [{text: "hi", value: 1}, {text: "world", value: 2}]
```

Then your code will look like this:

```
svg
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(data, d => d.text) // key function
  .join(
    (enter) =>
      enter
        .append('text')
        .text(d => d.text),
    (update) => 
      update
        .text(d.text),
    (exit) => exit.remove()
  );
```

Here, the second argument, the `d => d.text` function specifies how to diff the data. Instead of this function, you can put any arbitrary logic that returns a value. D3 will use this function when diffing to determine what goes in the enter, update and exit selections.

If our new data looks like this:

```
data = [{text: "hello", value: 1}, {text: "world", value: 3}]
```

Here, D3 uses the key function, in this case `d => d.text`. According to that function, the second element is the same, so it doens't go in any selection. But the first element has changed, so it goes in the `update` selection that you specify in the `join()`.

See [selection.data()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) and the [selection.join()](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) guide.

Comment: I did see the guide and tried to add keys without success. I guess it's my stupidity to assume that without changing the `update` part it would magically know how to merge things. I'm pretty sure adding `update.text(d.text)` part should allow d3 to differentiate whether it makes sense to make changes to DOM or not. I'll let you know if that works, I appreciate your help Hugo!